# triggering multiple cameras at the same time

Tags: camera, remote-control

any way to control multiple android cams  at the same time?from a PC?or if they are all connected to the same wifi

Comment: See if [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en) works for you.